# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, tkinter

Me estoy iniciando en el lenguaje de Python y en la plataforma, quisiera que me ayudaran un poco, ya cambie el tipo de variable (local, global) y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

No he encontrado el problema. También me sale el error acompañado de esto :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/PythonTriton/Clases/LoginWindow.py", line 5, in clicbotonIniciar
>     print(var.get())
>   TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
> ```

```
from tkinter import *

class LoginWindow():
    def clicbotonIniciar(self):

        print(var.get())
    def __init__(self):
        alto = "500"
        ancho = "500"
        window=Tk()
        window.title("Iniciar Sesión")

        pan_altura=window.winfo_screenheight()
        pan_ancho = window.winfo_screenwidth()
        res=round((pan_ancho/2)-(int(ancho)/2))
        res1=round((pan_altura/2)-(int(alto)/2))
        posicion="+"+str(res)+"+"+str(res1)
        anchoAlto=str(ancho)+"x"+str(alto)
        window.geometry(anchoAlto+posicion)
        window.resizable(False,False)
        window.iconbitmap("C:/Users/danie/Desktop/PythonTriton/Imagenes/Logo.ico")
        #window.overrideredirect(True)

        fuente="Arial Bold"
        fuenteBold="Arial Black"
        colorwindowFrame = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (51,51,51)
        color_rojo = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (255, 51, 51)

        windowFrame = Frame(window, width="500", height="500", bg=colorwindowFrame)
        windowFrame.pack()

        Imagen = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/danie/Desktop/PythonTriton/Imagenes/LoginPruebaN.png")
        Label(windowFrame, text="Iniciar Sesión",fg="white",bg=colorwindowFrame, font=(fuente,18) ).place(x=190,y=0)
        Label(windowFrame, image=Imagen,bg=colorwindowFrame).place(x=200,y=25)
        Label(windowFrame,text="USUARIO", font=(fuenteBold,18),fg="white",bg=colorwindowFrame).place(x=190,y=150)
        Label(windowFrame, text="CONTRASEÑA", font=(fuenteBold, 18), fg="white", bg=colorwindowFrame).place(x=160, y=230)
        Label(windowFrame, text="Llave de\nacceso", font=(fuenteBold, 10), fg="white", bg=colorwindowFrame).place(x=137,y=310)


        textUser=Entry(windowFrame,font=("Arial",20), width="15")
        textUser.place(x=140,y=190)
        textPass=Entry(windowFrame, font=("Arial", 20), width="15", show="*")
        textPass.place(x=140, y=270)
        textRec=Entry(windowFrame,font=(fuente,10), show="*",width="11")
        textRec.place(x=230,y=320)

        botonIniciar=Button(windowFrame, text="Iniciar", font=(fuenteBold,14), bd="4", bg="#FF5811", fg="white", justify="center", width="12",activebackground="#FF7E00", command= self.clicbotonIniciar)
        botonIniciar.config(cursor="hand2", relief="flat", activeforeground="gray")
        botonIniciar.place(x=80,y=430)
        botonRegistrar = Button(windowFrame, text="Registrarse", font=(fuenteBold, 14), bd="4", bg="#FF5811", fg="white", activebackground="#FF7E00",width="12")
        botonRegistrar.config(cursor="hand2", relief="flat", activeforeground="gray")
        botonRegistrar.place(x=270, y=430)
        botonRecordar=Checkbutton(text="Recordar",bg=colorwindowFrame,font=(fuenteBold,12), activebackground=colorwindowFrame, fg="#808080",activeforeground="#FF5811")
        botonRecordar.config(onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var)
        botonRecordar.place(x=137,y=350)
        botonCancelar=Button(windowFrame, text="X",bg=color_rojo, fg="white", font=(fuenteBold,11), width="2", activebackground="#FF4949", command = window.destroy)
        botonCancelar.config(cursor="hand2", relief="flat", activeforeground="white")
        botonCancelar.place(x=460,y=10)
        botonFAQ = Button(windowFrame, text="?", bg="#FF5811", fg="white", font=(fuenteBold, 11), width="2",activebackground="#FF7E00")
        botonFAQ.config(cursor="hand2", relief="flat", activeforeground="gray")
        botonFAQ.place(x=10, y=10)

        window.mainloop()
var = IntVar
ventanaLogin=LoginWindow()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, esté se era que tenia la función IntVar() declarada antes de la función de la librería Tk(). La solucion es declarar la tanto la instancia de Tk()(de manera global) afuera y consecutivamente la instancia o variable de IntVar()

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada es importante diferenciar entre una clase y un objeto.

`IntVar` es la clase, un objeto de este sería `var = IntVar()`.

Así como tú la estás declarando `var = IntVar` lo que le estás diciendo es que `var` es igual a la clase `IntVar`, no que es un objeto de la misma, para denotar un objeto es importante poner los paréntesis para que invoque al constructor y entonces se cree un objeto de este `var = IntVar()`

El error ocurre por lo mismo, todos los métodos que tienen como parámetro `(self)` solo pueden ser invocados por un objeto de dicha clase y no por la clase como tal.

Haciendo el cambio debería funcionar.

El código debería quedar como .

```
var = IntVar()
ventanaLogin=LoginWindow()
```

En esa parte, cambiando eso ese error ya no debería salir

Comment: Aún no entiendo bien. ¿Cómo sería el código con los respectivos cambios?

Comment: He editado la respuesta, agregando en donde tendrías que cambiar

Comment: Ya lo había intentado de esa manera. Ahora que lo intento me sale el siguiente error: **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/PythonTriton/Clases/LoginWindow.py", line 64, in <module>
    var = IntVar()
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 529, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 335, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'**